# Totalling returned values from functions php

Tags: php, function, laravel

I am using this to pull out some facebook data from a CSV

https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel

```
public function lifetime_likes_by_gender_and_age_f18_24()
{
    $result = $this->reader->select(array('lifetime_likes_by_gender_and_age_f18_24'))->get();
    return (int)$result->last()->sum();

}

public function lifetime_likes_by_gender_and_age_f25_34()
{
    $result = $this->reader->select(array('lifetime_likes_by_gender_and_age_f25_34'))->get();
    return (int)$result->last()->sum();;
}

public function lifetime_likes_by_female()
{
    return $this->lifetime_likes_by_gender_and_age_f18_24() + $this->lifetime_likes_by_gender_and_age_f25_34();
}
```

The problem is the first value is returned as  12 the second is 112. So the answer should be 124 but it is returning 136 which suggests it is doubling up the first value.

Any reasons why and how I can fix it? The PHP version is 7.

Comment: If you just return return $this->lifetime_likes_by_gender_and_age_f18_24() do you definetly get 12 every time?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the `select` method introduces a state to the reader, regarding selected columns.
So, when you run the 18_24 method you just select that, but then when you run the 25_34 the previous columns were never unselected, so you select them again.

Could you please try instead

```
public function lifetime_likes_by_gender_and_age_f18_24()
{
    $result = $this->reader->get(array('lifetime_likes_by_gender_and_age_f18_24'));

    return (int)$result->last()->sum();
}

public function lifetime_likes_by_gender_and_age_f25_34()
{
    $result = $this->reader->get(array('lifetime_likes_by_gender_and_age_f25_34'));

    return (int)$result->last()->sum();
}
```

I will read a bit more of the library source code, but that should be it.